# TypeScript out of order generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure I've worded the title of the question properly, however, it's the best I could come up with.

Say I have a function that accepts a callback and optional array. This callback takes in an index as well as (again optional) array, and returns a new value. The function returns an accessor object that has a method that wraps the application of the callback:

```
function createAccessor<T extends unknown[] | undefined, U>(
  indexfn: (index: number, arr?: T) => U,
  array?: T
) {
  return {
    valueAt(index: number) {
      return indexfn(index, array);
    },
  };
}

const x = createAccessor(() => 1);
const y = createAccessor((index) => index);
const z = createAccessor((index, v) => v![index], ["a", "b", "c"]); 
                                     // ^ Have to use non-null assertion operator here :( 
const w = createAccessor((index, v) => v![index]); // TypeScript should throw error here but doesn't

const x100 = x.valueAt(100); // 1
const y10 = y.valueAt(10); // 10
const z1 = z.valueAt(1); // "a"
```

I would like to type it such that if `indexfn` takes in index AND array, then `array` HAS to be provided to `createAccessor`, otherwise it can be left blank.

I can solve this by reversing the order of the parameters and explicitly passing `undefined`, e.g. `createAccessor(undefined, () => 1)` but I would prefer to not have to do that if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQL2YW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thanks for the quick response as always! Your solution looks intriguing & I never would've figured that out, I'm just a bit worried about the spread operator in the callback for performance reasons. Do you think there's no way to do it without it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with compiler-verified type safety, both from the caller's side and in the implementation, you can refactor to something like this:

```
function createAccessor<R extends [array?: unknown[]], U>(
    indexfn: (index: number, ...r: R) => U,
    ...r: R
) {
    return {
        valueAt(index: number) {
            return indexfn(index, ...r);
        },
    };
}
```

By using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of an [optional tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) for `array` instead of an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters), it allows the compiler to understand that you expect that `array` can be missing if and only if `indexfn` takes no params after `index`.  Your current version has both `array` and `arr` as optional parameters, so they can be present or absent independently.

Note that using a rest parameter also means we need to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for the final parameter so that the compiler understand what's happening (if you changed it to `indexfn(index, r[0])` the compiler would complain because it can't see that those are equivalent.

Anyway, this gives you the behavior you were looking for:

```
const x = createAccessor(() => 1); // okay
const y = createAccessor((index) => index); // okay
const z = createAccessor((index, v) => v[index], ["a", "b", "c"]); // okay
const w = createAccessor((index, v) => v[index]); // error!
const x100 = x.valueAt(100); // number
const y10 = y.valueAt(10); // number
const z1 = z.valueAt(1); // string
```

---

On the other hand if you want to keep your implementation the same (for performance reasons with the spread operator, I guess? But I'd be wary of [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)) but just make sure the callers are happy, you could use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to separate the two types of calls into distinct call signatures:

```
interface ValueAt<U> {
    valueAt(index: number): U;
}

// call signatures
function createAccessor<U>(indexfn: (index: number) => U): ValueAt<U>;
function createAccessor<T extends unknown[], U>(
    indexfn: (index: number, arr: T) => U, array: T): ValueAt<U>;

// implementation
function createAccessor(indexfn: (index: number, arr?: any[]) => any, array?: any[]
) {
    return {
        valueAt(index: number) {
            return indexfn(index, array);
        },
    };
}
```

That behaves quite similarly from the point of view of callers; either you call the function with one argument in which case `indexfn` must also accept one argument, or you call it with two arguments and `indexfn` must also accept two arguments... so `indexfn` and `array` are not *independently* optional:

```
const x = createAccessor(() => 1); // okay
const y = createAccessor((index) => index); // okay
const z = createAccessor((index, v) => v[index], ["a", "b", "c"]); // okay
const w = createAccessor((index, v) => v[index]); // error!
const x100 = x.valueAt(100); // number
const y10 = y.valueAt(10); // number
const z1 = z.valueAt(1); // string
```

The implementation is only loosely checked, so if you changed `return indexfn(index, array)` to `return "oopsiedoodle"` the compiler would not complain about it.  That might be fine, as long as you're careful and aware of the situation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAnjCBlEAzCALmkgN4BQZSVSuArsPAQJYD2wS8AThCARAILxEUKC04AeAEpIIADz7AAJlCQBtEJ04g0AfgBcSegGtgLAO7BVAXSsAaJAFUAfAApK1D0yVzcwAy69FOQNgWjAAIwhOewA6OM4DSQBKJABeJ0dbdw8qOJiEpElspBTyHOpuAlpOdjLynIA3EAAbWgECAO9ZELDIzlLi+pzK6vZAn2BOoNlY+KSAbkH6gF8soeXFj2Xi+DYoAiRZNI5uXgEhaFFOFxcU9KQARgWkAHoXpBYjbR29g+JUk48PiCYRXG7jWR3DIQ55vD5fNA-YD7JAAL2OXCB51BYnBXXsDShSAaqghdjUACIQBT7BTwjSkBT4BSrLD3p9vh5dsiDmYMadgRcRLipnICUSSWS2TJNGIAIRIlGyB4ABhVx1kMSarXaLlVKuloQiUUVf1VxzQWpabX4HVVht6Jq5vzRD2OqKtOtteul+04XgA5mRtqBILAEMgAPINKLNFggRSkCieYB8Ti4CNIABq1va4mcSaG2ptHQhPWN-QMDk21G2HjoDGYbEBZxBlzE+dcEN8-jLSCNfSJDiSBhzXoInZrVAbjFY7ExraFV3EKBk8ggShUxlMFms9mcbiG3b8SFF3X7juiSA0BRQQ-sN+0Bjvo9ztsnxRnTfnAux7eux69l05Z9A+mj6NewBoNYRIgFBYFaLoBhwdBVjFAMQwjDUhZDNQxa6n2A5RBhuHlFhYxdL4Z4IdoCxLOUqz0UgGzFNspqHPyWJtsK1y3GkGRPPMrzsgi7H-C2go4rxML8UgMJCXCHKIs6PJopxi5SXi0zirJkpdOSqhUgydLGcyrIKSJnLUNyKJ8gCC6Sf+WlisSEqkvp0pRJw8rscqaoap6JZ6mqDoVmJ5oApa+HevaFkXmFKkoqiboAh60V2r6BD+sAQbBkAA)